# Angular: using browser's HTML native build in validation error messages

Tags: html, angular, validation, constraint-validation-api

Is there a way to use browser's native HTML validation error messages and use them in angular way?

[image]

what I would like is to when having like a reactive form like this:

```
testForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  postCode: [{ value: 'postcode', disabled: true }],
  name: ['John'],
  city: [{ value: 'London', disabled: false }, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
});
```

to be able to use the native error messages in the form like:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" #myForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" formControlName="city" >
  <div class="errors">
    <p *ngFor="let errorCode in myForm.controls.city.errors">
      {{ getBrowserNativeErrorMessage(errorCode) }}
    </p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngNativeValidate` attribute in the `form` tag

```
<form ngNativeValidate>
</form>
```

But I don't think Reactive form `Validators` will work with this, you will have to use html native validation attributes

```
<input type="text" minlength="3" required>
```

Comment: yeah, I would like it to work both ways... especially reactiveForms way... and also I would like better control of it... maybe get the array of messages or object, so I can show the messages the way I want

Comment: You can try Angular Material, it provides in built features that works smoothly with reactive forms

Comment: Hmm... where? could you please point me to where I can harness the native error messages via ng material? I am using it but cannot find this functionality there

Comment: check [this](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-error), if this can help

Comment: that does not help me... this is what I am actually using to display the error messages... but this is just presentation... there is no actual business logic there... you need to build one yourself (checking if input is invalid and the cycle through control's errors... but you wouldn't get any error msg strings from there... unless you set them yourself